# Is there a way to run servlet Filter only once?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

Is there a way to define in `web.xml`, that certain servlet Filter must be executed only once?

Answer (score 1):

No. There the `Filter` is not for. Whatever the `Filter` is doing, should most likely be done by a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) instead.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during server startup.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during server shutdown.
    }

}
```

When you're still not on Servlet 3.0 yet, remove `@WebListener` and register it in `web.xml` the old fasioned way as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

If you really insist in using a `Filter`, you could abuse the `init()` method for the job and just call `chain.doFilter(request, response)` in the `doFilter()` method.

Answer (score 0):

A round about way would be to have class variable and set it on first access and have all functional code in an 'if' block that checks this variable..